# jQuery Plugin: Adding Callback functionality

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I'm trying to give my plugin callback functionality, and I'd like for it to operate in a somewhat traditional way:

```
myPlugin({options}, function() {
    /* code to execute */
});
```

or

```
myPlugin({options}, anotherFunction());
```

How do I handle that parameter in the code? Is it treated as one full entity? I'm pretty sure I know where I'd place the executory code, but how do I get the code to execute? I can't seem to find a lot of literature on the topic.

Comment: Your second syntax calls the function instead of passing it.  You need to remove the `()`

Comment: Personally I think you're better off having the callback be specified as part of the "options" parameter. That's especially true if it develops that there are more reasons than one to supply a callback.

Comment: How would something like that look, Pointy? Care to provide an answer-answer?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Just execute the callback in the plugin:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options, callback) {
    if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
        callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
    }
};
```

You can also have the callback in the options object:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // extend the options from pre-defined values:
    var options = $.extend({
        callback: function() {}
    }, arguments[0] || {});

    // call the callback and apply the scope:
    options.callback.call(this);

};
```

Use it like this:

```
$('.elem').myPlugin({
    callback: function() {
        // some action
    }
});
```

Comment: Just an add for this answer. There is a post that explains this: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-callback-functions-for-your.html

Comment: @David How to add callback parameter, I want to do this `$('.elem').myPlugin({ callback: function (param) { // some action } });`

Comment: @JeaffreyGilbert You should bring the jQuery context as well, I would do `options.callback.call(this, param);`

Comment: @David I want two callbacks, called `animateBefore` and `animateAfter`. please tell me how to use your solution ??

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly. But for the second version: This would call `anotherFunction` immediately.

Basically your plugin should be some kind of function that looks like this:

```
var myPlugin = function(options, callback) {
    //do something with options here
    //call callback
    if(callback) callback();
}
```

You have to provide a function **object** as callback, so either `function(){...}` or `anotherFunction` (without `()` ).

Answer (score 4):

Bringing back a blast from the past.

Worth noting that if you have two arguments passed, for example:

```
$.fn.plugin = function(options, callback) { ... };
```

Then you call the plugin without the options argument but with a callback then you'll run into issues:

```
$(selector).plugin(function() {...});
```

I use this to make it a little more flexible:

```
if($.isFunction(options)) { callback = options }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this might help you

```js
// Create closure.
(function( $ ) {
  
   // This is the easiest way to have default options.
 
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
 
            onready: function(){},
 
            //Rest of the Settings goes here...
        }, options );
 
    // Plugin definition.
    $.fn.hilight = function( options ) {
 
        //Here's the Callback
        settings.onready.call(this);
 
        //Your plugin code goes Here
    };
  
// End of closure.
  
})( jQuery );
```

I had shared a article about Creating your Own jQuery Plugin.I think you should check that  http://mycodingtricks.com/jquery/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Change your plugin function to take a second parameter.  Assuming that the user passes a function, that parameter can be treated as a regular function.
Note that you can also make the callback a property of the options parameter.

For example:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options, callback) {
    ...

    if(callback)        //If the caller supplied a callback
        callback(someParam);

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An example bit late, but it can be useful.
Using arguments can create the same functionality.

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    var el = $(this[0]);
    var args = arguments[0] || {};
    var callBack = arguments[1];
    .....
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        callback.call(this);
    }
}
```