# jQuery Pluggin. Adding both options and callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options describes how a plugin could have default options.

```
var settings = $.extend( {
  'location'         : 'top',
  'background-color' : 'blue'
}, options);
```

The second part of the selected answer [jQuery Plugin: Adding Callback functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534436/jquery-plugin-adding-callback-functionality) describes how to add a callback in the option object.

```
// extend the options from pre-defined values:
var options = $.extend({
    callback: function() {}
}, arguments[0] || {});

// call the callback and apply the scope:
options.callback.call(this);
```

How would I add both default settings and a callback function at the same time?  Also, I am a little confused on why I would extend the default callback function against arguments[0] or an empty object.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply merge both, you can have as many items in a object as you want

```
$.fn.myPlugib = function( user_options ) {  
    var options = $.extend({
        'location'         : 'top',
        'background-color' : 'blue'
        'callback': function() {}
    }, user_options || {});

    //now options object can be used to get callback or any other options when needed
    options.callback.call(this, options.location)
}
```

`user_options || {}` makes sure that if user hasn't provided any options we use empty options object

Comment: Wow, that was easy.  Any reason for lack a quotes around callback?  Also, why is arguments[0] || {} no longer required?  Thans

Comment: I am just merging user supplied options with our default options, so no need of checking optional first argument, also JavaScript dict work with or without quotes (except when name is not a proper variables name e.g. back-color), I just merged your two examples :)

Comment: Sorry, last one.  Why pass options.location back (i.e. options.callback.call(this, options.location))

Comment: @user1032531 I was just trying to give an example that now you can use callback and other attributes from the options dict

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last question, the extension on `arguments[0]` is equivalent to having an explicit paremeter called `settings` and doing:

```
$.fn.plugin = function(settings) {
    // extend the options from pre-defined values:
    var options = $.extend({
        callback: function() {}
    }, settings || {});

    // call the callback and apply the scope:
    options.callback.call(this);
}​
```

Comment: Thanks Juan.  Yes, I had searched "javascript arguments" and figured that out.  I then tried using both settings || {}, as well as just settings (without the || {}).  I did so both with and without sending it a settings object, but got the same results.  Maybe for cross browser support?  I am using FF 15