# jQuery - add after and before callback in plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-callback

I want to add after and before callback in my custom jQuery plugin.
I have never tried callback before. so please help me.

**This is my plugin code**

---

```
(function($){
    $.fn.OneByOne = function( options ){

        var defaults = {
            startDelay:5,           
            duration: 1000,
            nextDelay: 700
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var delay = options.startDelay;
        return this.each(function(){

            var o = options;
            var obj = $(this);                
            var a = $('a', obj);        

            obj.css({'margin-top':'100px','opacity': '0'});         
            obj.delay(delay).fadeIn().animate({opacity: 1,'margin-top':'0'}, o.duration);
            delay += o.nextDelay;


        });


    };
})(jQuery);
```

**where to call before and after callback**

---

I want to call `before` callback just before:

```
    obj.css({'margin-top':'100px','opacity': '0'});         
    obj.delay(delay).fadeIn().animate({opacity: 1,'margin-top':'0'}, o.duration);
    delay += o.nextDelay;
```

And want to call `after` callback just after above code.

**What I need callback**

---

I want to use

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

transition in my callbacks.

**Please also tell me how to use callback when calling plugin.**

thanks.

Comment: I understand you would like to have the plugin accept before and after callback definitions from the user?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534436/jquery-plugin-adding-callback-functionality

Comment: @sixFingers, Yes callback definition is given by user

Comment: @mightyuhu, I tried that solution, But i cant get it working.

Comment: @user1983017 mightyuhu is right, this is probably a duplicate. Another clarification: you want to use transit *in your callbacks*, but you're asking how to let the user define this callbacks. I can answer but let's try to avoid duplicating.

Comment: @sixFingers, I want to use different transit for each time the plugin called. So callback must be set when plugin is called

Comment: If I do understand you, you want to pass two functions(before and after callbacks) to your original function? Edit: Then add the two functions(diff. transit in your case) in your options object.

Comment: That's it. Simple pass the two functions to `options` in order to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let the user pass before and after callbacks.
   Inside your defaults, specify a default callback functions:

   ```
   var defaults = {
       startDelay:5,           
       duration: 1000,
       nextDelay: 700 
   };

   // Test if user passed valid functions
   options.before = typeof options.before == 'function' ? options.before || function(){};
   options.after = typeof options.after == 'function' ? options.after || function(){};
   ```

   Options in a $ plugin get passed in a hash, so users would pass them as

   ```
   $("…").OneByOne({…, before: function() {}, after: function() {});
   ```
2. In your plugin code, you have to hook to them so they get called (the default ones, OR any user defined callback):

   ```
   // Before is simply called before starting animation
   // Use call or apply on the callback passing any wanted argument.
   before.call(this, obj);
   // After callback is passed directly to animate function and gets called on animation complete.
   obj.delay(delay).fadeIn().animate({opacity: 1,'margin-top':'0'}, o.duration, after);
   ```
3. Any argument for "before" callback will be available in user defined before callback; after callback will be invoked with *obj* context, so inside any user defined after callback, $(this) *is* your obj.

Comment: I was about to answer the question until I saw yours. Right, but I it is better to test if the user has entered the before and after parameters as functions(using typeof or the jquery isFunction()) in order to execute some fallback mechanisms if not.

Comment: Or maybe it's ok not since many others do just fine with that, even one of the sample codes of a [jquery book](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) :)

Comment: Uhm, cant understand if you think it's ok or not :) Anyway, it's better to test, and also about that, there are better ways of testing if variable value is a function.