# Why callback functions are firing on page load : jQuery Plugins development

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

[image: here is code inspect in chrome when page loads]

I am trying to make a jquery modal plugin and can't understand why my callback functions are firing on page load? I need to fire two functions beforeStart before opening popup window and afterComplete after popup window opens not when page loads but all it occurs on page load. What's wrong with code. I googled  whole day still can't get it. [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534436/jquery-plugin-adding-callback-functionality)  also doesn't works for me.

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".selector").coolBox({
        OverlayClose: false,
        complete : function(){//this should called when my plugin finished its work
            console.log("complete");
        },
        beforeStart: function(){
            console.log("before Start");
        }
    });    
})
</script>
```

Edit: Here is full plugin code

```
 ;(function ($, window) {

$.coolBox = function (options) {

}
$.coolBox.closeCoolBox = function () {
    console.log("closeCoolBox closes");
    $("#clBoxOverlay,#clBoxOuterWrapper").remove();
};

$.coolBox.openCoolBox = function (options) {
    console.log("closeCoolBox opens");
    $("#inlineOverlayCloseDisabled").trigger("click");
    //$.fn.coolBox(options);
    $(this).each(function () {
        console.log($(this));
    })
};

  $.fn.coolBox = function (options) {
    console.log("calls to opens");
    var settings = {
        complete: false,
        beforeStart: false,
        Background: "#333",
        Opacity: "0.8",
        Padding: "10px",
        Height: "auto",
        Width: "auto",
        OverlayClose: true,
        EscClose: true,
        Zindex: "99991",
        Border: "2px",
        BorderColor: "black",
        PopUp: "fixed"
    };

    var o = {};
    $.extend(o, settings, options);

    //is this not for event handling before starting my plugin to change DOM?
    if (typeof o.beforeStart == 'function') {
        o.beforeStart.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
    }
    return this.each(function () {
        var link = $(this);

        link.click(function (event) {
            var clBox = document.createElement('div');
            clBox.setAttribute("id", "clBoxWrapper");
            document.body.appendChild(clBox);

            $clBoxWrapper = $("#clBoxWrapper");
            $clBoxWrapper.wrap($("<div id='clBoxOuterWrapper'></div>"));
            oBox = document.getElementById("clBoxOuterWrapper");
            oBox.style.width = o.Width;
            oBox.style.height = o.Height;

            if (o.PopUp == "fixed") {
                oBox.style.position = "fixed";
            } else {
                oBox.style.position = "absolute";
            }
            oBox.style.zIndex = o.Zindex + 1;
            var olBox = document.createElement('div');
            olBox.setAttribute("id", "clBoxOverlay");
            olBox.style.width = "100%";
            olBox.style.height = "100%";
            olBox.style.position = "fixed";
            olBox.style.zIndex = o.Zindex;
            olBox.style.opacity = o.Opacity;
            olBox.style.backgroundColor = o.Background;
            olBox.style.top = "0px";
            olBox.style.left = "0px";

            document.body.appendChild(olBox);

            $wrapContent = link.attr("href");
            //alert($wrapContent);
            if ($wrapContent.indexOf("#") == 0) {
                $wrapContainer = $($wrapContent).html();
                //alert($wrapContainer);

                $oBoxWrapper = $("#clBoxOuterWrapper");
                $clBoxOverlay = $("#clBoxOverlay");
                $clBoxOverlay.css({
                    "height": $(document).innerHeight(),
                    "width": $(document).innerWidth(),
                });

                if ($oBoxWrapper.length) {
                    $clBoxWrapper.html($wrapContainer);

                    if (o.PopUp == "fixed") {
                        $oBoxWrapper.css({"maxHeight": $(window).height()});
                        if ($oBoxWrapper.innerHeight() >= $(window).height()) {
                            $oBoxWrapper.css("overflowY", "scroll");
                        }
                        if ($oBoxWrapper.innerWidth() >= $(window).width()) {
                            $oBoxWrapper.css("overflowX", "scroll");
                        }
                    }

                    $oBoxWrapper.css({
                        "left": ($(window).width() - $oBoxWrapper.innerWidth()) / 2,
                        "top": ($(window).height() - $oBoxWrapper.innerHeight()) / 2
                    });
                }
            }
               event.preventDefault();
        });

   //is this not event handling code after my plugin finished it task?
        if (typeof o.complete == 'function') {
            o.complete.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
        }
    });        
}
})(jQuery, window)
```

It shows me the information in image when page loads but when i click on my selector link it does not fires my callback functions.

Comment: where's the event handling code? With what you've shown the logging makes sense

Comment: @charlietfl the loggging is to show that events are firing on page load not on when i want them to fire. Is `if (typeof o.complete == 'function') {}` is not event handling code? I read on net that it will fire functions passed to my plugin as callback functions.

Comment: really not clear what your expectations are.  Only reason you need `if (typeof)` is to make sure you don't throw error if it isn't a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fire **complete** callback function when the click event is fired, just move the call inside:

```
    ;(function ($, window) {
  $.fn.coolBox = function (options) {
    console.log("calls to opens");
    var settings = {
        complete: false,
        beforeStart: false,
        Background: "#333",
        Opacity: "0.8",
        Padding: "10px",
        Height: "auto",
        Width: "auto",
        OverlayClose: true,
        EscClose: true,
        Zindex: "99991",
        Border: "2px",
        BorderColor: "black",
        PopUp: "fixed"
    };

    var o = {};
    $.extend(o, settings, options);

    //is this not for event handling before starting my plugin to change DOM?
    if (typeof o.beforeStart == 'function') {
        o.beforeStart.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
    }
    return this.each(function () {
        var link = $(this);

        link.click(function (event) {
            var clBox = document.createElement('div');
            clBox.setAttribute("id", "clBoxWrapper");
            document.body.appendChild(clBox);

            $clBoxWrapper = $("#clBoxWrapper");
            $clBoxWrapper.wrap($("<div id='clBoxOuterWrapper'></div>"));
            oBox = document.getElementById("clBoxOuterWrapper");
            oBox.style.width = o.Width;
            oBox.style.height = o.Height;

            if (o.PopUp == "fixed") {
                oBox.style.position = "fixed";
            } else {
                oBox.style.position = "absolute";
            }
            oBox.style.zIndex = o.Zindex + 1;
            var olBox = document.createElement('div');
            olBox.setAttribute("id", "clBoxOverlay");
            olBox.style.width = "100%";
            olBox.style.height = "100%";
            olBox.style.position = "fixed";
            olBox.style.zIndex = o.Zindex;
            olBox.style.opacity = o.Opacity;
            olBox.style.backgroundColor = o.Background;
            olBox.style.top = "0px";
            olBox.style.left = "0px";

            document.body.appendChild(olBox);

            $wrapContent = link.attr("href");
            //alert($wrapContent);
            if ($wrapContent.indexOf("#") == 0) {
                $wrapContainer = $($wrapContent).html();
                //alert($wrapContainer);

                $oBoxWrapper = $("#clBoxOuterWrapper");
                $clBoxOverlay = $("#clBoxOverlay");
                $clBoxOverlay.css({
                    "height": $(document).innerHeight(),
                    "width": $(document).innerWidth(),
                });

                if ($oBoxWrapper.length) {
                    $clBoxWrapper.html($wrapContainer);

                    if (o.PopUp == "fixed") {
                        $oBoxWrapper.css({"maxHeight": $(window).height()});
                        if ($oBoxWrapper.innerHeight() >= $(window).height()) {
                            $oBoxWrapper.css("overflowY", "scroll");
                        }
                        if ($oBoxWrapper.innerWidth() >= $(window).width()) {
                            $oBoxWrapper.css("overflowX", "scroll");
                        }
                    }

                    $oBoxWrapper.css({
                        "left": ($(window).width() - $oBoxWrapper.innerWidth()) / 2,
                        "top": ($(window).height() - $oBoxWrapper.innerHeight()) / 2
                    });
                }
            }
               event.preventDefault();

               // THIS IS THE CALLBACK CALLED AT THE END OF CLICK
               if (typeof o.complete == 'function') {
                   o.complete.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
               }
        });
    });        
}
})(jQuery, window);
```

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/eyka9z0b/

Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works but for Complete callback, it doesn't work on beforeStart callback. It put `if (typeof o.beforeStart == 'function') {` inside ` return this.each(function () {` but it still fires on page load. I want it to fire when I click on my selector and my plugin just started its task. +1 for your answer. It really worked except beforeStart callback.

Comment: You're welcome! If I undertand your last comment, you want to trigger onBeforeStart callback on 'click', isn't it? I have update the jsfiddle ;) [link]http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/eyka9z0b/1/

Comment: You are awesome. I am going to mark it accepted. Just wanted to know one more think, where should i write code to close popup modal? I want to write something like this ` $.coolBox.closeCoolBox = function () {
        console.log("closeCoolBox closes");
        $("#clBoxOverlay,#clBoxOuterWrapper").remove();
    };` See my edits also.

Comment: Hey! Thank for the mark approved! I have update again de fiddle and added close event to the elements. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/eyka9z0b/2/