# jQuery custom callback for plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hey all I never have created a callback in a plugin before so help would be great.

I am wanting to add a callback to this action inside the plugin:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
   if (last) {
     if (e.target.innerText == "Yes") {
        $('[data-original-title=""]').text('Yes');
     } else if (e.target.innerText == "No") {
        $('[data-original-title=""]').text('No');
     }

     last.popover('hide').removeClass('popconfirm-active');
     //Do some type of callback here...
   }
});
```

So after seeing if its a **No** or **Yes** I would like to fire off a callback so that I can do things depending on the selected value.

The plugin intelization is this:

```
$("#button").popConfirm({
    title: "",
    content: "",
    placement: "bottom",
    yesBtn: 'Yes',
    noBtn: 'No'
});
```

And what I would like to do is this:

```
$("#button").popConfirm({
    title: "",
    content: "",
    placement: "bottom",
    yesBtn: 'Yes',
    noBtn: 'No',
    callback: function(btn) { // <-- added by me
      //Check btn for "Yes" or "No" then do something:
      //do something here...
    }
});
```

And the plugin code itself starts out like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    popConfirm: function (options) {
      var defaults = {
          title: 'Confirmation',
          content: 'Are you really sure ?',
          placement: 'right',
          container: 'body',
          yesBtn: 'Yes',
          noBtn: 'No'
        },
        last = null;
      options = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

So any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How to **add** a callback to an existing plugin that does not have one.

Comment: Well, you've already done that. You're supplying the function in the options. You just need to call it when required: `options.callback('your arguments here...');`

Comment: Here's a previous answer with some examples that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534436/jquery-plugin-adding-callback-functionality/#answer-2534466

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well that was easy enough. Go ahead and make that an official answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: That's ok, thank you - @delinear already pointed out this is a duplicate so I'll just close this for you